# I want to be able change the root directory using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to be able change the root directory using htaccess.

I want this:

`index.php/user/user_postdetail/index/14`

To become this:

`index.php/post_14.html`

I tried using

```
RewriteRule post_([0-9]+).html$ /index.php/user/user_postdetail/index/$1 [L=301,R]
```

but I am getting it reverse. Any ideas?

Comment: index.php/post_14.html here the number 14 is dynamic.    The exact page is index.php/user/user_postdetail/index/14 .Ineed this page has to redirected to     index.php/post_14.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. It should be `R=301` as it stands for **R**edirect with 301 code, whereas `L` means **L**ast rule to call.

Additionally, you do have it backwards.

What you need is:

```
RewriteRule user_postdetail/index/([0-9]+)$ /index.php/post_$1 [R=301,L]
```